# Expected traceback not shown on QgsRunProcess

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2.18

On QGIS 2.18 python console (windows 10) I execute:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRunProcess
myRun = "C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\hw.py"
QgsRunProcess.create(myRun,True)
```

where hw.py is a simple python script that contains:

```
try:
    print("Hello world!")
    os.mkdir("aaa")
except Exception as e:
    print("My Exception has been caught: {} ".format(e))
os.mkdir("bbb")
```

As there's no import for os, the expected output in the dialog should be as follows (as it is when I execute in a windows console):

`Hello world!
 My Exception has been caught: name 'os' is not defined
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./Desktop/hw.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.mkdir("bbb")
 NameError: name 'os' is not defined`

But what I get instead is:

`Starting C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\MyUsers\Desktop\hw.py...
 Hello world!
 My Exception has been caugth: name 'os' is not defined`

`Done`

with empty lines where the traceback should be shown.

Moreover I guess this could be related to stderrAvailable method (https://qgis.org/api/2.18/qgsrunprocess_8cpp_source.html  on line 103) but I can't see this error on the dialog, and I can't find how to get it shown there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `traceback`:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    print("Hello world!")
    os.mkdir("aaa")
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    formatted_exception = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)

    print("My Exception has been caught: {} ".format(e))

    print(repr(formatted_exception[0]))
    print(repr(formatted_exception[1]))
    print(repr(formatted_exception[2]))

os.mkdir("bbb")
```